# Why are these strings escaping from my regular expression in python?

Tags: python, list, iteration

In my code, I load up an entire folder into a list and then try to get rid of every file in the list except the .mp3 files.

```
import os
import re
path = '/home/user/mp3/'
dirList = os.listdir(path)
dirList.sort()
i = 0
for names in dirList:
  match = re.search(r'\.mp3', names)
  if match:
    i = i+1
  else:
    dirList.remove(names)
print dirList
print i
```

After I run the file, the code does get rid of some files in the list but keeps these two especifically:

> ['00. Various Artists - Indie Rock Playlist October 2008.m3u', '00. Various Artists - Indie Rock Playlist October 2008.pls']

I can't understand what's going on, why are those two specifically escaping my search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are modifying your list inside a loop. That can cause issues. You should loop over a copy of the list instead (`for name in dirList[:]:`), or create a new list.

```
modifiedDirList = []
for name in dirList:
    match = re.search(r'\.mp3', name)
    if match:
        i += 1
        modifiedDirList.append(name)

print modifiedDirList
```

Or even better, use a list comprehension:

```
dirList = [name for name in sorted(os.listdir(path))
           if re.search(r'\.mp3', name)]
```

The same thing, without a regular expression:

```
dirList = [name for name in sorted(os.listdir(path))
           if name.endswith('.mp3')]
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) I'm new to python and there's a bunch of things to learn!

Comment: your list comprehensions are nonsense.

Comment: @SilentGhost - Nonsense? How so?

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Ok, found the error, you can't sort on os.listdir(path). You have to do it on your own list.

Comment: You can use `sorted(os.listdir(path))`.

Comment: Ahh, `sorted()` is what I meant. Fixed

Answer (score 3):

maybe you should use the glob module - here is you entire script:

```
>>> import glob
>>> mp3s = sorted(glob.glob('*.mp3'))
>>> print mp3s
>>> print len(mp3s)
```

Comment: `glob.iglob` would be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you call `dirList.remove(names)`, the original iterator doesn't do what you want. If you iterate over a copy of the list, it will work as expected:

```
for names in dirList[:]:
    ....
```

Alternatively, you can use [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to construct the right list:

```
dirList = [name for name in dirList if re.search(r'\.mp3', name)]
```